# Making Kendo ToolBar moveable

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

Is there any way to make the Kendo ToolBar a floating toolbar that can be moved around ?
I'm trying to accomplish the same look and feel of the inline editor toolbar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a kendo draggable on that toolbar.. here is a simple [example](http://dojo.telerik.com/@diondirza/IMIji) of it

Comment: Thank's , it is indeed draggable, however it becomes off centered when I start to drag.  I'll play with it.

Comment: that's a simple example, you can modify it like what you want. I hope you are not just copy and paste it ;)